# Простейшая аутентификация / авторизация в SPA + Web API

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

У меня есть простая апишка на ASP.NET Core и клиент на React. В апишке нужно сделать так, чтобы один роут был не доступен без аутентификации = там данные, которые в админке будут показываться. Мне нужна ровно одна роль = или пользователь вошел(тогда это админ и у него есть возможность сделать запрос на нужный эндпоинт) или нет(и доступа тогда нет). Как проще всего это реализовать, в какую сторону смотреть ? Подойдут ли куки для этого ? (клиент только браузер).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чем вам не нравится аутентификация, как в MVC?

Куки можно юзать в зависимости от ваших потребностей. Если нужно можете использовать даже jwt токены и отправлять "секретный" url на почту, либо коды какие-то, что угодно)

Можете вот [тут](https://www.endpointdev.com/blog/2022/06/implementing-authentication-in-asp.net-core-web-apis/) посмотреть более детально